# Hide quick actions panel when opening Google Maps (Lite Mode replacement)

Tags: google-maps

I used to open Google Maps in Lite Mode on my mobile with the following URL:

> https://www.google.com/maps/@?force=lite

Since a couple days / weeks, I've noticed that the interface has changed, and particularly, the highlighted panel below is automatically opened:

[image: screenshot]

That means that I have to make one extra clic after opening Google Maps in order to hide that panel.

Google is [saying](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3031966?hl=en) that Lite Mode is being deprecated:

> ## Other versions of Google Maps on the web
>
> Maps in Lite Mode is currently being upgraded to full Google Maps. If you’re using Google Maps on your computer and the map doesn’t scroll or pan smoothly, there are other versions you can use.
>   [...]

Without Lite Mode, is there any way to automatically hide that panel when opening a Google Maps URL?

*PS: I can't use any ad-blocking addon.*

Comment: how about using app? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.mapslite

Comment: @user0 I'm not using Android.